# How to use single_media_upload

Tags: sulu

I am looking for an example for simple use of `single_media_upload` in SULU AdminUI.

I have a player form, and it has `single_media_selection` type of field, and it works OK.

Now, how can I use `single_media_upload`, because, when I replace it instead of `single_media_selection`, it shows not picture in form after save (but it saves image).

```
<property name="photo" type="single_media_selection" colspan="4" >
            <meta>
                <title>playerinfo.playerimage</title>
            </meta>
            <params>
                <param name="types" value="image"/>
            </params>
        </property>
```

I replace with

```
<property name="photo" type="single_media_upload" colspan="4" spaceAfter="2">
                <params>
                    <param name="upload_text">
                        <meta>
                            <info_text>app.player_info_upload</info_text>
                        </meta>
                    </param>
                    <param name="skin" value="default"/>
                    <param name="empty_icon" value="su-user"/>
                    <param
                        name="collection_id"
                        type="expression"
                        value="service('sulu_media.system_collections.manager').getSystemCollection('sulu_media')"
                    />
                </params>
            </property>
```

In Entity itself, field is `MediaInterface` type.

Answer (score 0):

The `single_media_upload` field-type is not interchangeable with the `single_media_selection` type. It was implemented for managing the avatar/logo of the built-in contact/account entity and was not optimized for other usecases yet. At the moment, the `single_media_upload` creates a new media version for the selected media entity rather than creating a separate media entity when uploading a file. This behaviour differs substantially from the `single_media_selection` and might not fit your usecase. This is also the reason why the field-type is not listed in the [Sulu documentation](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/reference/content-types/) yet.

That said, the reason for your problem is likely that the `single_media_upload` field-type uses a different data format than the `single_media_selection`. **In general, the field-types of the Sulu form view expect that your API returns the data in the same format as it is sent to the server when submitting the form** (see the [Form configuration section](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/book/extend-admin.html#form-configuration) in the Sulu documentation). You can see the data that is sent to the server by inspecting the request that is made when pressing the save button in the [network panel development tools of your browser](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/).

In the case of the `single_media_upload` field-type, the data that is sent to the server looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": 33,
  "url": "/media/33/download/photo-1535683939029-0030b4de2382.jpeg?v=1",
  "thumbnails": {
    "sulu-400x400": "/uploads/media/sulu-400x400/03/33-photo-1535683939029-0030b4de2382.jpg?v=1-0",
    ...
  }
}
```

If you want to use the field-type in the form of your custom entity, you need to **adjust your controller (or the serialization of your entity)** to match this format.

Comment: How can I show image instead of displaying thumbnail in input box? Is there a way to make it like that?